# Cannot display date pipe on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I want to display a date pipe with angularjs and firebase to show when the I create a post. When there are is a list of posts and when I see the details of the post but it doesn't show anything when I test it.

Here is my create Post function:

```
createPost() {
    const data = {
      author: this.auth.authState.displayName || this.auth.authState.email,
      authorId: this.auth.currentUserId,
      content: this.content,
      image: this.image,
      published: new Date(),
      title: this.title
    };
```

Next is the post list html:

```
<section>
    <mat-card *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
        <mat-card-content routerLink="{{post.id}}">
            <img src="{{post.image}}" alt="{{post.title}}">
            <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
            <p><small>Posted by {{post.author}} &bull; on {{post.published * 1000 | date: 'fullDate'}}</small></p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions align="end" *ngIf="auth.currentUserId === post.authorId">
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="delete(post.id)">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</section>
```

And post detail html:

```
<div [hidden]="editing">
        <mat-card>
            <img src="{{post.image}}" alt="{{post.title}}">
            <p>
            <small>Posted by {{post.author}} &bull; on {{post.published * 1000 | date: 'fullDate'}}</small>
            </p>
            <mat-card-content>
                <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{post.content}}</p>
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions align="end" *ngIf="auth.currentUserId === post.authorId">
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="editing=true">
                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="delete()">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
```

Also when I hover over the **Date** in the **published: new Date(),**
it has this message:

> const Date: DateConstructor
>
> new () => Date (+4 overloads)

Is there any problem with that if you know, tell me what to change to make the date pipe to show on my posts.

Comment: Why do you multiply the `published` Date with 1000?

Comment: For some reason when I test it. It doesn't show the posted by and published instantly and I have to click to another post to see it and with the * 1000 it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write this in post list html and post detail html:

```
&bull; on {{post.published.toDate() | date: 'fullDate'}}
```